# How to write Markdown List in one line?

Tags: markdown

I'm trying to put a list in one line using Markdown, however, something like "`* Item 1 * Item 2 * Item 3`" doesn't work and SHIFT+ENTER is needed. `<br>`s just break the list.

Comment: "I'm trying to put a list in one line"—why? This seems like a pretty obvious case of "don't do that".

Answer (score 1):

What you are currently trying to do looks like italicized text so the leading and trailing `*`s will convert the text to something like the following:

*Item1 * Item 2* Item 3

So writing a list in one line isn't exactly possible. Markdown is meant to be a readable text tool. According to the original release on [Daring Fireball](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/):

> Markdown allows you to write using an **easy-to-read**, **easy-to-write** plain text format

That being said, you can use HTML in some Markdown tools. You'll have to read the documentation of your used Markdown tool to figure this out. If using HTML is possible then you can write the list with `<ul>` and `<li>` elements like so:

```
<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ul>
```

However, this is extremely bad practice as it is not easy-to-read at all.
Instead, I urge you to use the indented syntax of one item per line starting with either a `*` or `+`.

```
* Item 1
* Item 2
* Item 3
```